# Audacity - export selection across all tracks.

Tags: editing, audio-recording

Using Audacity, how can I export my selection but across all tracks? Say I only want from 0:30 to 0:50 of my timeline, but all non-muted tracks. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your selection on one track, then either select Edit->Select->In All Tracks or press Ctrl+Shift+K.  This will make the selection across all tracks.

You can then export your selection.

Any muted tracks will not be in the final mix.